# How to get system notifications in iOS

Tags: ios, scheduled-tasks, system, nsnotifications

I want to get all the system notifications in my app and want to scheduling them. Is it possible in iOS ? Example - Suppose my mail app is on. When a email arrives, a notification appears there. I want to catch that notification in my app for scheduling either in foreground or background. How can i do it ? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: There is no way to observe activity taken by other apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible.  In iOS notifications are "owned" by an app.  There is no way you can read the other apps notifications.

Moreover, as you probably know, iOS gives the user the ability to limit the types of notifications your app displays.